# How can I boost my life and mana?

Tags: torchlight

In Diablo II, if I don't have enough life, I can increase my vitality.  If I don't have enough mana, I can increase my energy.

In Torchlight, there doesn't seem to be a way to directly increase life or mana, unless I've missed something.  Have I?

And if not, then what *is* the best way to improve life and mana stats in Torchlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life and Mana are increased as you gain level. You can only increase them though items with the attributes "+XX Health" or "+XX Mana" or replenish them with the "+XX Mana/Health stolen per hit."